# dojo cross domain json returning as script

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to grab a [songkick json feed](http://www.songkick.com/developer/upcoming-events-for-artist) using the below:

```
var jsonpArgs = {
    url: obj.url,
    load: function(data) {
        console.log(dojo.fromJson(data));
    },
    error: function(error) {
       new ErrorDialog({ title: 'Error', content: error });
    }
};
    dojo.io.script.get(jsonpArgs);
```

It loads the data fine, but it returns:

> Resource interpreted as script but
>   transferred with MIME type
>   application/json. Uncaught
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

This unexpected token coming from the contents of the file (line 1):

```
    { "resultsPage":
```

I'm guessing it's because the content coming back isn't be interpreted as json properly but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have tried specifying the callback parameter but it does nothing (not jsonp?).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the feed does not support JSONP responses. Looking at their modest documentation I don't see how to specify a callback (the crucial part of JSONP). So obviously you are getting an error — JSONP uses `<script>` to retrieve the data, yet the data is of wrong type.

Another thing is you have to specify `jsonp` parameter, which is callback parameter. But it looks like a moot point, because I don't see your feed service supporting it.

So you best bet is to do a server-side call to this service using a proxy or something similar. This way you avoid cross-platform problems and can deal with JSON or XML directly.